# Implement Google Maps into blazor component in .NET MAUI

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, maui

I am trying to implement Google Maps into my Blazor component, but I cannot have Javscript inside the blazor component, how do I manage to get the Map into my Blazor component?

Here is my code:

Map.razor

```
@page "/map"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h3>Map</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
        let map;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                zoom: 8,
            });
            alert("test");
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAg8GuCi6zrFU1wARf_pKOm6qDvrH9pqW0&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
            defer></script>


}
```

But that doesnt work, so I tried to move the  to the index.html file and then make the Map.raxor file like this:

```
@page "/map"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h3>Map</h3>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap");
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var test = ex;
        }


    }
}
```

But I get the exception: `Map: Expected mapDiv of type HTMLElement but was passed null.\`

Comment: Use `OnAfterRenderAsync()` instead of  `OnInitializedAsync()`. Also, did you forget to include `<div id="map">/div>` in your `Map.razor` component? It's not there in the second code snippet you added.

Comment: This solved it! Thanks! (missed to ad map to the map.razor in this post, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OnAfterRenderAsync() instead of OnInitializedAsync()

Answer (score 0):

In your js function there is not element with id="map", so it crashes

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map")
```

Just adding the id:

```
@page "/map"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h3>Map</h3>
<div id="map"> </div>
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap");
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var test = ex;
        }


    }
}
```