# Access google maps on MAUI Blazor, Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, maui

I have seen articles about creating the c# code about making maps available. But there is no explanation on how to add it to the razor pages in Blazor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;


namespace Visitor.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                Map myMap = new();
            }
            base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@page "/"

<myMap />
```

Comment: Blazor (whether in Maui or in a browser) runs web browser code. You can't use a mobile device's Map control there; you need some browser solution. Search `google maps in blazor` or perhaps `leaflet in blazor`.

Comment: You may use a JavaScript interop to add it to the razor pages in Blazor. For more details, you can refer to [Implement Google Maps into blazor component in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040851/implement-google-maps-into-blazor-component-in-net-maui).